# Golang - spotify: can't oAuth with zmb3

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, token, spotify

i'm trying to create an oAuth thanks to the zmb3 library (https://github.com/zmb3/spotify) but i have trouble with it.

i get my url and send it to my front like so, then the refront redirect to the url:

```
func GetSpotifyUrl(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
fmt.Println("ok")
url := auth.AuthURL(state)
res, _ := json.Marshal(url)
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
w.Write(res)
}
```

At this stade, i'm able to press the button "agree" and perform a redirection to my callback function:

```
func AuthSpotify(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
tok, err := auth.Token(r.Context(), state, r)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Couldn't get token", http.StatusForbidden)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if st := r.FormValue("state"); st != state {
    http.NotFound(w, r)
    log.Fatalf("State mismatch: %s != %s\n", st, state)
}

client := spotify.New(auth.Client(r.Context(), tok))
// infinite loop on this line ^^^

fmt.Fprintf(w, "Login Completed!")
ch <- client 
}
```

but in this function i have an "infinite loop" at the line where i assign client. I can print the token `tok`, and the value seems good.

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot